# DAX, Calculating Average of a measure within a hierarchy

Tags: powerbi, dax, average

I need to solve an issue that I am having with DAX, but I cant find the right query.
To give you some context: I have different regions in my data that have the values T100, T200, T300 and so on. They can be found in the column RegionLevel2 in the table Geography. Then , in the same table there is a column called TerrLevel1 that has the territories. Each region has multiple territories. So for example the territories for region T100, are T101, T102, T103 and so on. For each of these territories I have calculated a Score, based on their individual sales. It is a measure called Score1 and working fine. Now I need to calculate the score for the regions. This score is based on the average of the sales of a regions territories. So in the case of T100, its score would be the average of the Score1 of T101, T102, T103 and so on. I have tried these DAX formulas :

```
AVERAGEX(Geography, [Score1])

AVERAGEX(all(Geography[TerrLevel1]), [Score1])

AVERAGEX(VALUES(Geography[TerrLevel1]), [Score1])

CALCULATE( AVERAGEX(Geography, [Score1]),ALL(Geography[TerrLevel1]))
```

but it is not giving me the right result. I guess i need to filter somehow to group the right territories with their region but I cant figure out how.

I would appreciate any kind of help. Thank!

**For Promethee:** first column are the territories (they are as G0101 and such instead of T0101 as described above), second table is the score of each territory (the measure that should be used for the average) and last column is the result I get from your query. [temporay result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHf39.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have no territory context, your original measure (that I'll name "Avg") should work.
Now assuming you have a context with a territory:

- you have to cancel the territory context with ALL;
- then this could depend on whether or not you have an explicit region context:

If region context is explicit, this should be sufficient:

```
=IF(HASONEVALUE(Geography[RegionLevel2]),
    CALCULATE([Avg],
              ALL(Geography[TerrLevel1])),
    BLANK())
```

but I suggest you to consider that region context might not always be explicit and thus use the following (safer) measure:

```
=IF(HASONEVALUE(Geography[RegionLevel2]),
    CALCULATE([Avg],
              Geography[RegionLevel2] = VALUES(Geography[RegionLevel2]),
              ALL(Geography[TerrLevel1])),
    BLANK())
```

The disadvantage of this measure is that you'll get no value (blank) if several regions belong to the context (typ. in totals or subtotals) but I don't know your exact needs.

**For Promethee:**
first column are the territories (they are as G0101 and such instead of T0101 as described above), second column is the score of each territory (the measure that should be used for the average) and last column is the result I get from your query.
[temporary result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BCeb.png)

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply! I have replaced your [Avg] with AVERAGEX(Geography, [Score1]) or AVERAGEX(all(Geography[TerrLevel1]), [Score1]) , but i get the same results as if I used  both of them without the script you provided. The Score1 measure that I have calculated is not the average yet. I need to extract it. Do you have an idea how?

Comment: Basically, [Avg] should be
"=AVERAGE(Geography[Sales])". This is (as far as I understood) the raw measure pointing onto column "Sales" of table Geography.

Comment: Yes, the only problem is that sales is already a measure, so I would need to use Averagex() right? The different ways I tried are unfortunately not working though. is there any other way?

Comment: I misunderstood you. I thought that Score1 was just the average of the column. So it's actually a score; can you please provide the formula for this measure?

Comment: Sure thing! The measure itself is a calculation of four other measures that I previously created: Score1 = [Product1 40%] * 0.4 + [MS Product1 60%] * 0.6) * 0.5 + ([Product2 40%] * 0.4 + [MS Product2 60%] * 0.6) * 0.5  .  I would not focus too much on this measure since there is a lot of logic behind. But basically it just calculates the score of each territory. But calculating the average of the scores of the territories that share the same region turns out to be more challenging than expected. Maybe I have to group them fist and then take the average? Im just think how I'd do it in sql...

Comment: I'm still not sure I perfectly got your point but if you want the unweighted score average among all territories of a same region, this should work:
"=IF(HASONEVALUE(Geography[RegionLevel2]),
    CALCULATE(AVERAGEX(VALUES(Geography[TerrLevel1]), [Score1]),
              Geography[RegionLevel2] = VALUES(Geography[RegionLevel2]),
              ALL(Geography[TerrLevel1])),
    BLANK())"

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the result in the main section for you, so it is more understandable. The average I get for the first Region (all territories starting with G01) is 5.86, but it should be 5.426.

Comment: I've tested the DAX formula in Excel with some random data before posting and I see the average score: 
[Test in Excel](https://ibb.co/F8tWZYb)

Comment: Strange... do you have any idea of what could be the problem? I cant figure it out

Comment: Well, in my last formula the AVERAGEX calculates independently the measure Score1 for each unique value of Geography[TerrLevel1] (thanks to VALUES) belonging to the region which the original territory belongs to (thanks to the modified context introduced by the CALCULATE) and then performs the average of these independent Score1 values. So I don't see what could be wrong.
Based on my tests, it works whatever the kind of aggregations in sub-measures [Product1 40%], etc (as expected).
So without any table sample, I have no explanation.

Comment: Could it be due to some filters maybe that I am using on Territory level? In the measures that are used to calculate the measure Score1 I have different filters:
Geography[Region_LINE] = "T" (its to filter for the regions that start with T only)

and then there is also a calculate :

CALCULATE([Product2 40%], REMOVEFILTERS(GEOGRAPHY[DES_TERRNIVEL1_FILTER], GEOGRAPHY[DES_TERRNIVEL2_FILTER]), REMOVEFILTERS(DIM_GEO_NO_RLS[DES_GEONIVEL3_FILTER], DIM_GEO_NO_RLS[DES_GEONIVEL4_FILTER])).

I tried to include them but could not find a way to make it work. Do you know how maybe?